# Determining when scrolled to bottom of a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to determine when I've scrolled to the bottom of the page (without using any JS library), but so far, I'm a bit confused over which one of the following to use.  The most promising one I've seen is `window.scrollY`, but even when scrolled to the bottom of the page, it never matches the value of `window.innerHeight`.  What's the best way to do this?

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight

window.outerWidth
window.outerHeight

window.scrollX
window.scrollY

document.body.scrollWidth
document.body.scrollHeight
document.body.scrollTop
document.body.scrollLeft

document.body.offsetTop
document.body.offsetLeft
document.body.offsetWidth
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Comment: Why take the hassle of dealing with events manually instead of using a JS library like jquery?

Comment: Because if you don't understand how to do it you won't be able to build libraries like jquery

Answer (score 26, accepted):

when `window.innerHeight` + `document.body.scrollTop` is greater than or equal to `document.body.offsetHeight` then you are at bottom

but since IE has issues with these properties you need to use alternative properties, like

`document.documentElement.scrollTop` for the scroll and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` for the window height

full code: http://jsbin.com/egegu3/6/edit

Answer (score 6):

Being a lazy person at heart, I would put an element to the very bottom of the DIV, and apply the "[element in view](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/)" jQuery plugin on it. (Disclaimer: I have no own experience with it but it looks good.)

A slight variation of the example from the blog entry:

```
$('#bottomDIV').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    highlightButtons(); // or whatever you want to do in the context
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This works fine:

```
 window.onscroll = function()
 {
    var scrollHeight, totalHeight;
    scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    totalHeight = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;

    if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight)
    {
        console.log("at the bottom");
    }
}
```