# Alert using Jquery when Scroll to end of Page

Tags: jquery, browser-scrollbars

Is there a way to find out page end using Jquery, so that a simple message can be displayed saying you have reached end of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining when scrolled to bottom of a page with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[How to tell when you're at the bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript)**:

```
if (  document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
      $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )
{ 
    // Display alert or whatever you want to do when you're 
    //   at the bottom of the page. 
    alert("You're at the bottom of the page.");
}
```

Of course you want to fire the above whenever the user scrolls:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (  document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
          $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )
    { 
        // Display alert or whatever you want to do when you're 
        //   at the bottom of the page. 
        alert("You're at the bottom of the page.");
    }
});
```

**[Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrjkq/)** that fades in a "You're Done! Scroll to Top of Page" link when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.

**References:**

- **[`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)**
- **[`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)**
- **[`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight)**
- **[`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight)**

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I recommend the accepted answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: @Ryan - Does the jsFiddle not work for you? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 6):

This will work and I tested it in IE 7,8,9 , FF 3.6, Chrome 6 and Opera 10.6

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop()  <= $(this).height())
    {
        alert('end');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the above solutions don't work please check if you set your document type right:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Took me an hour to find out :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate `console.log('end of page')`, you need create a setTimeout, like this:

```
var doc = $(document), w = $(window), timer;

doc.on('scroll', function(){

    if(doc.scrollTop() + w.height() >= doc.height()){

        if(typeof timer !== 'undefined') clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('end of page');
        }, 50);

    }

});
```

Comment: Alternatively you could remove the event listener after the first successful execution (console.log)

Answer (score 0):

It might need tweaking to account for browsers, but something like this should do:

```
$(document).scroll(function()
{
    var $body = $('body');
    if (($body.get(0).scrollHeight - $body.scrollTop) == $body.height())
    {
        // display your message
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for debugging: I was getting the alert on return to the top of the page(?) using 
jquery-1.10.2.js. Loaded jquery-1.6.4.min.js and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var a = 1;
         
         //this function triggers whenever scroll is detected
         window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            
           //this condition is used to trigger alert only once
            if(a == 1){  

                //this condition check whether user scrolled to the 
                //bottom of the page or not
                if(($(document).height()-2) <= 
                scrollY+$(window).height() ){
                     alert('end of the page');
                     a = 0;
                 }
            }
      })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.