# Call function on scroll end

Tags: jquery

I want to call a specific function when the Scroll reaches at the Bottom END of the page.

Here is my Code m using but its not working for me. No console errors, but still not working.

```
$(function() {

    var scrollEnded = $.debounce(500, false, function() {

    console.log('scroll ended');

           alert("ok"); // I will call my function here. Just need an alert.

    });

});
```

Comment: Cant you do a check on `window.scroll` and than check the offset till top?

Comment: this might help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609255/javascript-jquery-perform-function-when-user-scrolls-near-bottom-of-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function

```
$(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
           alert('I am at the bottom');
           // Here goes your code.
       }
   });
});
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xGV8Q/1/)

Comment: this alert function will call if we set scroll at the middle of the page then reload the page ... why is that ?