# Waypoints ain't working when scrolling too fast to the bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints

on my website : http://www.entendu.info/ i'm using the waypoints plugin from http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

If the user scroll directly to the bottom, most of the waypoints ain't triggered, only the 2 first one and the last one, as if the middle ones are scrolled too fast to be executed.
(waypoints are the social buttons which are loaded when scrolled )

Any help ? 
PS : head.ready is just an alternative of document.ready when using headjs to load external script.

```
head.ready(function() {

opts = {

        offset: '85%',
        continuous: 'true',

    };


 //$('.share-this').on('click', function(e){


$('.share-this').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   if (direction === 'down') {


    var contentId = $('.share-this').attr('rel');
    var uri = $('.share-this').attr('rev');



    $.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.entendu.info/share',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: {id:contentId, url:uri},
   complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

   },
   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

   $('#'+contentId).html(data);

   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   }
   });


   }
   else {

      // do this on the way back up through the waypoint
   }
   //});

   $.waypoints('refresh')
   }, opts);



});
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but can you try using the version that's on the master branch of the repo and not the 1.1.6 build.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can achieve what you want without having to use an extra jQuery plugin. Details can be found on this post so, all credit due where neccessary.

[How to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

The long story short is, you can use the [scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) already provided with the jQuery framework and compare the document height against the currently displayed window height. I don't want to steal someone elses thunder though, check out the links.