# How to hide a div at the end of the vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div at the bottom of the screen in fixed position with an arrow inside. How do I hide the div when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Please post your code, with samples of what have you have tried already.

Comment: I think it's already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom, :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('div').hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var vericalscroll= document.height - (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
```

if your `vericalscroll` is 0,it means you have reched at the end of vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery for this:

```
var max_scroll = 500;
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= max_scroll)
  {
      $('#my_div').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

where `my_div` is your div name and `max_scroll` is the scrolled position.