# Use jQuery to detect when an element is near the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script that works out the distance of a list of elements from the top of the page, but I am unsure how to detect it's distance from the bottom. When it hits the bottom (well, 20px before the bottom) I want to fire an event and fade it out:

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function () {
    $('.links__item').each(function () {
        if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0)
        } else {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1)
        }
    })
})
```

If anyone has any advice, much appreciated. I'm looping through the elements to detect it, so when one of them hits 20px from the bottom, I want to fade it out. Thanks!

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3898152/1823841

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the jQuery function `height()` at your calculations, like:

```
$(window).height();
$(this).height();
```

Specifically, if you want to detect if the top of the element is near to the bottom of the page, you can use this calc:

```
if ( $(this).offset().top > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 20) ) // True
```

Answer (score 4):

Halcyon,

I am not sure what you want to fire but you can test the bottom of the page like this

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function () {
    $('.links__item').each(function () {
        if( ($(this).offset().top > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 20)) {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0)
        } else {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1)
        }
    })
})
```

Reason being is jQuery finds bottom of the page based upon its height

```
1 $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
2 $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Comment: Bruno got there just quicker with the identical answer, but thank you very much anyway :)!