# Check if user scroll to bottom of the page work opposite

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to detect if user scrolled to the bottom of the page so I can make some action.
But I did something wrong and when I scroll to the bottom nothing happens but when I scroll to the top it fires the action :(.
And should opposite :)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {        
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && !($('#imgLoad').is(':visible'))) {
            alert('you hit bottom');
            loadMore();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try this one

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

you can also have another option on the following question:
[Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: Same behavior. When I scroll to the bottom nothing but when back to the top fired.

Comment: And what scares me the most is this work in IE but not in FF & chrome.

Comment: I will accept this answer to close the question as this works the same as mine code. The issue is in another area. I posted it in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685692/custom-dnn-skin-cant-detect-bottom-scroll-but-it-works-reversed-7-1-1

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but posting in case this helps someone else in the future. I was experiencing the same problem. The event would fire as I scrolled to the top of the page from the bottom. Using document.body.clientHeight instead of $(window).height fixed things for me. This was tested using Chrome.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight == $(document).height()) {
        alert('bottom of page');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.body.offsetHeight + document.body.scrollTop>= document.body.scrollHeight){
    alert("bottom!");
}
```

Comment: You're right. I accidentally entered the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
     // when scroll to bottom of the page
    }
});
```

Comment: Same behavior. When I scroll to the bottom nothing but when back to the top fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-200) {
                alert();
                // add your custom function here. i.e what you want to do.
            }
```

This will work.The user scrolls down the page and when the if(condition) is met the code is executed.

Comment: This works as I scroll it load new elements. But this way I never can't hit bottom.

Comment: what are you loading? are you loading the contents dynamically?

Comment: @1110 : you should know exactly how much is you content. Then only you can track it.

Comment: I am using DotNetNuke and ASP.NET. I have a module that detect bottom of the page and via jquery.ajax return data to the page. I am using jquery masonry plugin to return 50 by 50 elements.

Comment: @1110 : Look when the page loads for the first time make a jquery ajax request for getting the count of total number of elements or the contents you want to load and store it in a javascript global variable, then when you scroll down just load the remaining contents on the page using jquery ajax. send the count by ajax and get the remaining elements.

Comment: @1110 If you do not know the end of your content then you cannot find the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
following scroll function would be worked while window scrolling bottom in asp.net
$(window).scroll(function() {    
$(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight == $(document).height()
});

and following scroll function would be worked while window scrolling bottom in html or mvc page view.
$(window).scroll(function() {    
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()
});
```