# Custom dnn skin can't detect bottom scroll but it works reversed (7.1.1)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

*First I thought this is JS issue but this is skin issue.*
**And to mention that this issue is happening to the Chome and FF but in IE it works for some reason.**
I am designing skin for the first time for **DNN** and it goes fine until I find out that I have made something wrong :(.

I have created a simple skin that have on content pane. In that content pane I added my custom module that load elements dynamically when user scroll to the bottom of the page (I append new elements to the div).

And my module work fine on "`DarkKnightSkin`" but on my custom skin I think that I have miss something so any help is welcome :)

**Problem is** that when I scroll to the bottom nothing happens. But when I scroll to the top it fires action and do what it need to do. What I did wrong here?

This is skin.ascx

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="top-bar-menu">
            <div id="top-bar-menu-logo-holder">
                <dnn:LOGO runat="server" ID="dnnLOGO" />
            </div>
            <div id="user-account-box" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;">
                <dnn:USER runat="server" ID="dnnUSER" />
                <dnn:LOGIN runat="server" ID="dnnLOGIN" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="main-navigation-menu">
            <ddr:MENU ID="MENU1" MenuStyle="Superfish" runat="server">
                <ClientOptions>
                    <ddr:ClientString Name="speed" Value="fast" />
                </ClientOptions>
            </ddr:MENU>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main-content-holder">
        <div runat="server" id="ContentPane"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is skin.css

```
body {
    background:#fff;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:62.5%; /* Sets default font size to 10px */
    color:#222222;
    }

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

img {
    border:0;
    }

p {
    margin-bottom:1.75em;
    }

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#B4C835;
    }
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#6CC7DC;
    }

header, footer, nav, section
{
    display: block;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#wrapper {
    background:#ffffff;
    font-size:1.20em;
    }

#top-bar-menu{
height: 52px; 
color: #000;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#user-account-box a{color:#000 !important;}

#top-bar-menu-logo-holder{
width: 150px;
}

#top-bar-menu-logo-holder img{
max-width: 50px;
}

#main-navigation-menu{ 
color:#000;
width:450px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index:10000; 
}

nav
{   
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CFCACA;
}
```

In my module:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {        
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && !($('#imgLoad').is(':visible'))) {           
            loadMore();
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
I created a new `skin.asmx` and `skin.css` (empty file) and put only this:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SOLPARTMENU" Src="~/Admin/Skins/SolPartMenu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="PRIVACY" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Privacy.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="~/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGIN" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Login.ascx" %>

<div runat="server" id="ContentPane"></div>
```

My module still render fine but on scroll bottom doesn't work and on back to top work (*still reversed*).

**UPDATE 2**

```
html, body, address, blockquote, div, dl, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, p, pre, table, ul, dd, dt, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, button, del, ins, map, object,
a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, kbd, q, samp, small, span, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, legend, fieldset {margin:0;padding:0;}
img, fieldset {border:0;} img {max-width:100%;height:auto;} .ie8 img {width:auto;height:auto;} 
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display:block;}
html {height:100%;}
body {background:#eeeeee url(images/mbg.jpg);font: 100%/1.2 Droid Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#333;min-height:100%;overflow-x:hidden;}
    p {margin: 0 0 1.6em;padding:0;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;}
    table{}
    a {text-decoration:none;outline:none;color:#834202;}
        a:hover {color:#000;text-decoration:underline;}
    big {font-size: 16px;}  small {font-size: 87%;} strong, b {color: #41322a;} em, i {font: italic 115% Baskerville, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
    em strong {color: #8e3d17;font: bold 70% "Lucida Grande", Arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: .1em;}
    ul, ol {margin:1.2em 0 1.4em 3em;padding:0;} li{margin:0 0 .3em 0;padding:0;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;}
    code {font-family: Consolata, monospace;font-size: 100%;color: #72008a;word-spacing: -.25em;}
    pre code {background: #f3efc3 url(images/line-bg.png) 0 7px;overflow-x: auto;display: block;width: 95%;padding: 2% 2.5%;margin: 30px 0;clear: both;color: #585535;font-size: 85%;line-height: 140%;border: solid 1px #e8e3b8;border-bottom: solid 1px #d9d4a8;}
    blockquote {font: italic 130%/140% Baskerville, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;background: url(images/quote.png) no-repeat 5px 0;padding: 0 30px 15px;}
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:Droid Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:130%;font-weight:bold;color:#453630;margin:1.4em 0 .6em;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;}
    h2{font-size:1.6em;font-weight:bold;color:#2a353c;clear:both;letter-spacing:-0.035em;margin:1em 0;line-height:1;}
        h2.dnnPEMContTitle .Head, h2 .Head{font-size:1em;}
    h3 {font-size:125%;margin:0.5em 0 .3em;letter-spacing:-.04em;}
        h3 em {color: #8f0206;font: italic normal 100% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
    h4 {margin: 1em 0 .2em;font: italic 155% Baskerville, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
    form p {margin:0;padding:6px 0;}
    /*form label {font-size:0.825em;}*/
    form label small, form label em {text-transform: none;color: #8c8c86;font: italic 90% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
    /*input, textarea, select {font-size:100%;font-family:inherit;}*/
    input[type=text] {width:240px;max-width:96%;}
    textarea {line-height:150%;width:96%;}
        textarea:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=text]:focus {outline: none;background: #faf7dd;}
    input[type=reset], input[type=submit] {background: #68584c;text-transform: uppercase;color: #fff;border: none;padding: 7px 20px;border-bottom: solid 1px #55473b;cursor: pointer;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);-webkit-border-radius: 5px;  -moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;-webkit-appearance: none;}
    input[type=reset]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover {background: #3f332a;color: #fff;}
    .clear{clear:both;overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at what JS resources are loaded by DarkKnight (either look at the ASCX, or view the HTML source of a page with the skin applied) and see which resources are loaded there, that aren't loaded on your skin file.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for answer. I explored DarkKnight skin and just copy-paste head of css file. I think that all this code is some kind of css-reset. And now it works fine. I can't say why but it works. Code is in my question UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into something like this, try putting `form {height: 100%;}` in your CSS. That has solved page height problems for me. DNN wraps everything inside a form tag and it is easy to forget that it is there.