# detect when textarea is scrolled to bottom

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to gauge when a user has scrolled to the bottom of an element? I know that jQuery can access the `scrollTop()` of an element, but even combining that with the element's height, I cannot calculate when an element has been scrolled to the bottom-most position. I would like to do this so when scrolling within a textarea I can prevent the body of the document from scrolling once the "scroll bottom" of the textarea is reached.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/enIyUYi/1/edit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: The logic in this can be used to suit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17450817/2592585

Comment: @ChristianTernus This seems to work for the window, but how can I apply it to the textarea?

Comment: Thanks @Vizkos but how can I apply this to just the `textarea`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/BW8LT/1/

```
$('textarea#mytextarea').on('scroll', function() {
    var offset = 200; // height of textarea

    if (this.scrollHeight <= (this.scrollTop+offset)) {
        console.log('end of textarea!');
    }
});
```

**Edit 1**: *disable scrolling by hiding the overflow*

```
$('textarea#mytextarea').on('scroll', function() {
    var offset = 200; // height of textarea

    if (this.scrollHeight <= (this.scrollTop+offset)) {
        // hide the overflow (=> disable scrolling) when the end is reached
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }
});

// re-enable scrolling on mouseout
$('textarea#mytextarea').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
});
```

Just compare `textarea.scrollHeight` with `textarea.scrollTop`.

Take a look at your console while scrolling. Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't see a downvote, and I cannot understand why anyone would. This works great, thanks! How could I implement it so that the document would stop scrolling when the console displays its messages?

Comment: You'd like to disable scrolling for your whole page/document when the end is reached? I didn't understand your Question, I guess. Please let me know more details.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be the best method. But then re-enable it when the cursor leaves the textarea, so that scrolling could be re-enabled. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why do you want to disable scrolling? Doesn't sound user-friendly, in my opinion. You should let decide the user if he'd like to scroll or not. What's your plan behind this idea?

Comment: if the user is scrolling down a thousand lines in a textarea, when he or she arrives at the bottom don't make the page suddenly scroll down to the bottom. Only when the mouse is over an element that's not the textarea allow that.

Comment: Sounds well meant but could confuse the user - I wouldn't do that. I just edited my answer, just take a look.

Comment: It's basically just a tool for me, so should be okay. Your solution is perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/okeFeZo/1/edit)):

```
$('textarea').scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - 4) {
    alert("You scrolled to the bottom!");
  }
});
```

Comment: isn't `$(this)[0]` equivalent to `this` ?

Comment: The bin for this solution is not working, the alert doesn't fire.