# trigger event on reaching browser bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(window.reachBrowserBottom) {
    alert('browser bottom reached');
  }
}
```

I want to trigger an event when browser scrolling reaches the bottom. To load more content, much like sites like Facebook or Quora do it.

I tried:-

```
var bottomReached =  $(window).height() = $(window).scrollTop();
if(bottomReached) {
   ...
}
```

But `bottomReached` is a bit [unpredictable](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this answer. It addresses the same issue.

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898152/1341823](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898152/1341823/)

You need to use the `.scroll()` event on `window`.

Comment: @SangramSingh You could also check out the wonderful Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin by Paul Irish. http://www.infinite-scroll.com/