# Parallax with arrow scroll downj

Tags: jquery, parallax

I use parallax to scroll down my page.

But now i need create a icon/arrow allways visible when the user click scroll down to the next page, like this example.

http://cyclemon.com/index.html

Thanks

I have a menu works fine,

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#intro">HOME</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I add a arrow,

```
 <a href="#intro"><img src="imgs/icone_down.png" /></a>
```

The link works but dont add the scroll efect like parallax...

Allmost there

now i have,

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
          $("#click").click(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
}, 1000);
            //});
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="#second"><img src="imgs/icone_down.png" /></a>
```

Ok fine, now i detect if we reached the bottom, but how can i hidde the arrow?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what they did: add an element high in the DOM tree with:

```
.arrow {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px; // or whatever 50% the width of the arrow is
}
```

Then use JavaScript to scroll the page by X amount (say, window.innerHeight+"px") every time it is clicked. I would use jQuery to make the animation nice and smooth:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
}, 1000);
```

Comment: ok and the link??? i add the arrow and it is visible but i cant add the link... to scroll to the next page

Comment: use jQuery .scrollTop() to scroll and trigger the link.

Comment: If you use the animate block I posted in my answer, you should be able to smoothly transition down the page.

Comment: Khior now works fine thanks a lot... i just have a little question, if i have in the middle of the page one page that i dont whant have the arrow to scroll down, for example in the last page dont need have the arrow to scroll donw because dont have next page... how can i do it?

Comment: You can detect if you have reached the bottom of the page by detecting it in jQuery and then hiding the arrow if it is true (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: Khior i only have a little problem... if you scrool in the arrow in the penultimate and the last div you see a little space in the top, the div dont reaches up totally, you now why this happens?