# When scroll to footer load more items?

Tags: php, jquery

I have to call a `php function` in jQuery post method to load more elements and append them to  the body dynamically when it scroll to footer.

Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: You're looking for "infinite scroll". Google it. Try something; anything. Come back with an actual question.