# End of scroll on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I just implement an infinite scroll without plugins in JavaScript with jQuery but it doesn't work on mobile browser. Works fine on computer browser..

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
          alert('bottom');
    }
}
```

I just want to load content when the scroll reaches the bottom. It doesn't work on iPhone, iPad and Nexus 5 browser. What can be the problem?

Comment: What do `$(window).scrollTop()`, `$(window).height()` and `$(document).height()` return when you reach the bottom?

Comment: On desktop version 1042,867,1909 . But on mobile never enters the if condition

Comment: And on the iPhone, iPad and Nexus 5 browsers what are the values then scrolling (visually) at the bottom?

Comment: Then it is probably horizontal scroll bar not taken into account... Try to use this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10795797/2195721] solution.

Comment: `scrollTop` is flaky on mobile devices — further compounded by rubber-banding and the way events are generated. You could try `offset().top` instead.

Comment: What do i use $(document).offset().top ?