# How to repeat a function call in jQuery after my function worked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    iScroll = iScroll + 200;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: iScroll
    }, 1000);
}, 2000);});
```

it works properly and it scrolls automatically my page but i want when scrolling ends go to beginning and repeat scrolling automatically , What is the problem?

thanks great man @lessugar
i solved my problem :)
here is my code

```
setInterval(function () {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    iScroll = iScroll + 200;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: iScroll }, 1000);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you want it to scroll back and forth, or skip back?

Comment: You need to detect the end of the page and provide "back-scroll" code. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: i exactly want when my page load, automatically scroll my web page and when it finish, automatically go top and scrolling down again! :)

Comment: @ardalanpegah You should be putting your solution in the answer section, not the question. :)

Comment: @indieblue this is my firs question :) ill do it for another ;)