# Using multiscroll.js. Want to invert arrow after reaching end of slide

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, multiscroll.js

I am using multiscroll.js in my page. See below.

```
$('#myContainer').multiscroll({
    sectionsColor: ['#116a9e'],
    anchors: ['welcome', 'second', 'third'],
    menu: '#menu',
    navigation: true,
    navigationTooltips: ['1', '2', '3'],
    loopBottom: true,
    loopTop: true
});
```

And I have arrow points down and I want if I reach the end of my page that arrow has to point up. But I'm not able to use below this.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
function onScroll(){
console.log("Hello");
$('.arrow-scroll').toggleClass('scroll-down scroll-up')
}
```

This code never gets called. If I 'click' in place of 'scroll' everything works fine.

Comment: It looks like this has been answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ==     $(document).height()) {
            console.log("ddddd");
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

});

I used like this. I does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiScroll.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or translate3d property of the site. Therefore your `scroll` event won't even be fired. The site has no scroll.

You should be using the callback [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) and adding your code there.

Something like:

```
$('#myContainer').multiscroll({
    sectionsColor: ['#116a9e'],
    anchors: ['welcome', 'second', 'third'],
    menu: '#menu',
    navigation: true,
    navigationTooltips: ['1', '2', '3'],
    loopBottom: true,
    loopTop: true,

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){

        //supposing you have 4 sections on your site
        //this will fire when you reach the last one
        if(index == 4){
             $('.arrow-scroll').toggleClass('scroll-down scroll-up');
        }
    }
});
```