# jQuery height doesn't equal scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery I am trying to calculate when the scrollbar is 100px from the bottom, and when it gets there I will do an ajax query (for now I am doing an alert as you can see).

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(e){
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollHeight);
    console.log(offset);
    if(scrollHeight - offset <= 100){
        alert("here");
    }
});
```

For some reason that I can not figure out it doesn't work. If I scroll to the bottom I would assume that the `height()` would equal `scrollTop()` but it doesn't, and here is what it shows:

```
scrollHeight = 1923
offset = 998
```

Am I using the wrong methods for this?

Comment: You'll have to subtract the windows height, as `scrollTop` is the top of the window.

Comment: Also, using [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight) is probably more accurate than the documents height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the height of the `window` with `scrollTop`. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cpmf7xps/1/)

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if (docHeight - (scrollTop + windowHeight) <= 100) {
        alert(docHeight - (scrollTop + windowHeight));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be forgetting to subtract the pane's view-able height. I've done something similar in my code here:

```
          var scrollPos = $('#viewable-div').height() - $('#scrolling-content').height();
          if ($("#scrolling-content").scrollTop() > (scrollPos - 100)) {
              //load more 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll the element all the way down, scrollHeight should be equal to scrollTop + clientHeight.

If the element has no scrollbars scrollWidth/Height should be equal to clientWidth/Height.

•   When the element has no scrollbars IE makes the scrollHeight equal to the actual height of the content; and not the height of the element. scrollWidth is correct, except in IE8, where it’s 5 pixels off.

•   Opera gives odd, incorrect values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a statement like this

```
((container.scrollTop() + container.height() + detectionOffset) >=
         container.get(0).scrollHeight)
```

Where container could be the document.body and detectionOffset would be 100

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a few times before, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

One piece of code that I'm using and is always working (even on Opera) is this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
            var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
            var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
            if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
                /* Do something */
            }
       });
```