# Unable to detect whether user reached the bottom of the page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to detect whether user reached the bottom of the page.

The following code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom) doesn't work in Chrome with the scale different than 100% (alert window does not pop up):

```js
function bottomReached() {
  return $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height();
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (bottomReached()) {
      alert('Bottom reached');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
<h2>Scroll?</h2>
</br>
```

It works as expected in Firefox though.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Same here. Chrome 47.

Comment: I can reproduce. Key difference is that the page can't be at 100% scale. That's interesting.

Comment: @j08691 Which scale did you try?

Comment: @j08691 It doesn't work for me with 75%. Which version do you use?

Comment: Tested on Win7/Chrome 47.0.2526.73 m

Comment: @j08691 I'm using the same version. Where did you run this code? Did you try it on localhost / any site like JSFiddle?