# Sub-menu fadeIn at the top of the page and fadeOut at the end

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sub-menu, that fadeIn at the top of a page if you scroll 150px. If you higher than the 150px it fadeOut.

That's works fine. Now I want that the sub-menu FadeOut at the end of the side, too. 
Like: 
FadeIn between 150px of the top and 150px before the page ends. Outside this area: FadeOut.

Here is my jQuery-Code:

```
function scrollSide($) {

if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    /*menu scroll*/

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 150) {

            $("#navbar-example").fadeIn("easing");
            $(".sidemenu").css("top", "92px");

        } else {
            $(".sidemenu").css("top", "170px");
            $("#navbar-example").fadeOut("easing");

        }
    });
   } 
}
```

I need a if statement for the situation between the top of the page and the end of the page.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/3898130/2887133

Comment: Yeah, I've found that post... but I didn't found a good solution to use it.
The sub-menu was flashing if you scroll down because the function was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add another condition to your `if` statement, checking if the user has scrolled to the bottom or not.

Based on this question:

[Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

You can do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(window).scrollTop(),
        wh = $(window).height(),
      dh = $(document).height();
  if(st >= 150 && st+wh <= dh-150){
    $('yourdiv').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('yourdiv').fadeOut();
  }
})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vvcLp4hr/)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       $(window).unbind('scroll');
       alert("near bottom!");
   }
});
```

Note:-Changing $(window).height() to window.innerHeight should be done because when the address bar is hidden an additional 60px are added to the window's height but using $(window).height() does not reflect this change, while using window.innerHeight does.