# Scroll to top link for website using pure JAVASCRIPT without(jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I want normal scroll to top for website.

The scroll to top link appears at the bottom of page(near footer) which only visible after 200px mouse scroll down and should be hidden when scroll back to top. WITHOUT `JQUERY`

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/sturobson/pen/equnb)

In this demo back to top is already at the bottom. Is there any way to show back to top link fixed as I mention above?

Comment: I think this answer will help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

**HTML**

```
<a id="scroll_to_top_id"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#scroll_to_top_id {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background
}
```

**PURE JAVASCRIPT(NO JQUERY)**

```
/*
 *  Scroll To Top
 */

var your_header        = document.getElementById('header_id'),
    scroll_to_top   = document.getElementById('scroll_to_top_id');


window.onscroll = function(ev) {

    var  scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > your_header.offsetHeight + 100) {

        scroll_to_top.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        scroll_to_top.style.display = 'none';   
    }
};

scroll_to_top.onclick = function () {
    scrollTo(document.body, 0, 100);
}

/*
 *  scroll to body top
 *  element, position and time duration
 */
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
        if (duration < 0) return;
        var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
        var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want it as simple as possible, just use:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">
```

this will scroll you to the top of your site.

Answer (score 2):

For this case, the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) leave an awesome solution, we can now use the following example:

```
const el = document.getElementById('the-scroll-box');

el.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth', // or can get `auto` variable
});
```

The `behavior` if have `smooth` value, the scrolling motion is smooth if have `auto` value the motion happen in one jump.