# UWP WebView catch scroll event

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-phone

I used to have a scroll viewer for terms and conditions, when the user scrolled to the bottom I made the accept button active so they could only proceed once they scrolled.

I used to catch the scroll to bottom event using this code:

```
scrollViewerMain.ViewChanged += ScrollViewerMain_ViewChanged;
```

and

```
private void ScrollViewerMain_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_scrolledToBottomEventHandlerHit)
    {
        return;
    }

    var verticalOffsetValue = scrollViewerMain.VerticalOffset;
    var maxVerticalOffsetValue = scrollViewerMain.ExtentHeight - scrollViewerMain.ViewportHeight;

    if (maxVerticalOffsetValue < 0 || verticalOffsetValue == maxVerticalOffsetValue)
    {
        _scrolledToBottomEventHandlerHit = true;
        // Scrolled to bottom - trigger event
        ScrolledToBottom(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

This was working fine, but now the  terms and conditions come as html, so I have to use the `WebView` control so the formatting is correct. There isn't a `ViewChanged` event - so how can I achieve the same result - when the user scrolls to the bottom of the `WebView`, the button is enabled?

Comment: I dont think you can get end of the scroll event. You have to do it by invoking the Javacsript. If you dont have any user interactions in webview there is a work arround

Answer (score 0):

The `WebView`'s scroll bar is not accessible to the app directly, because it is a part of the embedded Edge browser view. You can however solve your problem using `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` method, where you can invoke a script, that will check for the time when the user reached the end of the page.

```
await web.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
```

Such scripts can be found [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom).

To actually notify your C# code, when the user scrolls down to the bottom, you will also need to inject a **web allowed object**. A great tutorial for that is available [here on Martin Suchan's blog](https://www.suchan.cz/2016/01/hacking-uwp-webview-part-2-bypassing-window-external-notify-whitelist/). You can use this injected object to notify back your C# code about the event and then enable the button in that method.