# Scroll Down (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a scroll down who works with 2 buttons, one button to start and the other to stop. But if I press the start more times it won't stop. Also what I can do to stop when arrives in the end of the div/page?

HTML

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    <!--εδώ γράφω-->
    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
        <button onclick="start_scroll_down()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow" style="width:46%" style="position:fixed;">Start SD</button>
        <button onclick="stop_scroll_down()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow" style="width:46%" style="position:fixed;">Stop SD</button>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <center>
            <!--text-->
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function start_scroll_down() {
    scroll = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1);
        console.log('Ξεκίνα');
    }, 150);
}

function stop_scroll_down() {
    clearInterval(scroll);
    console.log('Σταμάτα');
}
```

Comment: Just call `stop_scroll_down()` in the first line of `start_scroll_down`

Comment: in my opinion you need to track location, if a certain height is reached then the stop_scroll_down() is invoked.

Comment: Side note: don't use `<center>`

Comment: Try to use jquery.scrollTo plugin ,https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: Have a look at this: https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/OgJMeW

Comment: Just out of interest, why are all the answers here downvoted? What exactly is wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you click you generate a new interval (and then lose all reference to the old one, making it impossible to clear later on, **overwriting an interval does not stop it**):

```
function start_scroll_down() { 
    scroll = setInterval(function(){
        window.scrollBy(0, 1); 
        console.log('Ξεκίνα');
    }, 150);
}
```

So instead of always generating an interval immediately, clear the existing one first, that way you won't have more than one:

```
function start_scroll_down() { 
    clearInterval(scroll);
    scroll = setInterval(function(){
        window.scrollBy(0, 1); 
        console.log('Ξεκίνα');
    }, 150);
}
```

As a side note, `scroll` is a function already defined within `window` (`window.scroll(x, y)`, it scrolls to a specific location) and you should consider renaming your variable to something else to ensure you don't overwrite the original:

```
function start_scroll_down() { 
    if(myScroll){clearInterval(myScroll)};
    myScroll = setInterval(function(){
        window.scrollBy(0, 1);
        console.log('Ξεκίνα');
    }, 150);
}
function stop_scroll_down() {
    if(myScroll){clearInterval(myScroll)};
    console.log('Σταμάτα');
}
```

Note the `if` statement to protect the code from failing the first time it is run (i.e. when `myScroll` is undefined).

You can detect how far you have scrolled by comparing the current scroll distance to the total height of the page:

```
myScroll = 0;
function start_scroll_down() { 
    if(myScroll){clearInterval(myScroll)};
    myScroll = setInterval(function(){
        window.scrollBy(0, 1);
        console.log('Ξεκίνα');
        if(window.scrollY == document.body.offsetHeight-window.innerHeight){
            clearInterval(myScroll);
        }
    }, 150);
}
```

Note that here I have ensured that `myScroll` is already defined *before* setting the interval, otherwise `clearInterval(myScroll);` will throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

## Stopping once at the bottom of the element

Lets adjust your scrolling function to check how far down we are before continuing. (using jquery, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom))

```
function scrollPage() { 
  const scrolledHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  const atBottom =  scrolledHeight == $(document).height();
  if (atBottom) { stop_scroll_down(); }
  else { window.scrollBy(0, 1) }
}
```

## Clicking button multiple times

You need to detect if you are already running the scroll function or not. This can be done as such:

```
let isScrolling = false;
let scrollInterval = null;

function start_scroll_down() { 
  if (isScrolling) { return; }
  scrolling = true;
  scrollInterval = setInterval(scrollPage, 150);
}

function stop_scroll_down() {
   clearInterval(scrollInterval);
   isScrolling = false;
   console.log('Σταμάτα');
}
```