# how to use scroll event in angular material mat select?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

i have a large list and i want to load it as the user scroll down the select field but how can i get the scroll event in mat-select there is no event that fire the scroll event.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose a Doctor" formControlName="selectedDoc" (change)="drSelected()">
    <div *ngFor="let dr of doctors;let i = index" [matTooltip]="getDocDetail(i)" matTooltipPosition="right">
      <mat-option (scroll)="docScroll()" [value]="dr">
        {{dr.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-hint>List Of Doctor In Your city</mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selectedDoc.hasError('required')">Please Select A Dr</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

(scroll) don't work because mat-select don't have any scroll event any other way i can achieve this i want to show like 10 item first then populate the rest item when user scroll end of the options .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-load-on-scroll?embed=1&file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.ts) I created.

In your component, get the `MatSelect` via `ViewChild` to access its scrollable panel. Then add an event listener to the panel, which reloads the doctors and updated the `viewDoctors` array when the `scrollTop` position exceeds a certain threshold.

```js
allDoctors = ['doctor', 'doctor', ..., 'doctor'];
viewDoctors = this.allDoctors.slice(0, 10);

private readonly RELOAD_TOP_SCROLL_POSITION = 100;
@ViewChild('doctorSelect') selectElem: MatSelect;

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectElem.onOpen.subscribe(() => this.registerPanelScrollEvent());
}

registerPanelScrollEvent() {
  const panel = this.selectElem.panel.nativeElement;
  panel.addEventListener('scroll', event => this.loadAllOnScroll(event));
}

loadAllOnScroll(event) {
  if (event.target.scrollTop > this.RELOAD_TOP_SCROLL_POSITION) {
    this.viewDoctors = this.allDoctors;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to assign your `mat-select` to a variable in your template so that you can access it via `ViewChild`:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose a Doctor" #doctorSelect>
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    <mat-option *ngFor="let dr of viewDoctors;let i = index">
      {{dr}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is only a very basic setup illustrating the idea. You might want to do show a loading animation,  cleanup the event listener,...

Comment: thanks a lot kim kern this code helped me a lot i was looking for this for 3 days can you just explain what should be the value of RELOAD_TOP_SCROLL_POSITION if i choose 100 i don't get scroll event if i use low value like 10 i get a lot of scroll events .

Comment: The scroll events get triggered every time the user scrolls, independent from the threshold. It just ensures that the user has scrolled down a bit until it starts the reloading. It will repeat the reloading, when the user scrolls down, so you should probably remove the event listener so it only reloads once. Unfortunately, there is no perfect value, strongly depends on the use case, the client,...

Comment: Property 'onOpen' does not exist on type 'MatSelect'

Comment: @WasifKhalil In a newer version, `onOpen` was replaced by `openedChange`.

Answer (score 1):

To this date, infinite scroll for `mat-select` component is still not available and kept as an open issue. Meanwhile,  have a look at [ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/HaidarZ/ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll), you can use it to lazy load your data.

```
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatSelectInfiniteScrollModule} from 'ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSelectInfiniteScrollModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Component**

```
  total = 100;
  data = Array.from({length: this.total}).map((_, i) => `Option ${i}`);
  limit = 10;
  offset = 0;
  options = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);
  options$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.options$ = this.options.asObservable().pipe(
      scan((acc, curr) => {
        return [...acc, ...curr];
      }, [])
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getNextBatch();
  }

  getNextBatch() {
    const result = this.data.slice(this.offset, this.offset + this.limit);
    this.options.next(result);
    this.offset += this.limit;
  }
```

**Template**

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
    <mat-select msInfiniteScroll (infiniteScroll)="getNextBatch()" [complete]="offset === data.length">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options$ | async" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Here's a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Kim's answer, the scroll height and top can be used to detect when the user has reached the bottom of the dropdown (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wanted%20to%20instead,scrollTop()%20%2B%20%24(window).))

I also updated the logic to load the next 10 records on scroll in case the full dataset was too large to load in one shot.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

@Component({
  selector: 'toolbar-multirow-example',
  templateUrl: 'toolbar-multirow-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['toolbar-multirow-example.css']
})
export class ToolbarMultirowExample implements OnInit {
  allDoctors = Array.from(new Array(3000).keys()).map(i => 'Doctor ' + i);
  viewDoctors = this.allDoctors.slice(0, 10);
  viewIndex = 0;
  windowSize = 10;  
  private readonly PIXEL_TOLERANCE = 3.0;
  @ViewChild('doctorSelect') selectElem: MatSelect;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectElem.openedChange.subscribe(() =>
      this.registerPanelScrollEvent()
    );
  }

  registerPanelScrollEvent() {
    const panel = this.selectElem.panel.nativeElement;
    panel.addEventListener('scroll', event => this.loadNextOnScroll(event));
  }

  loadNextOnScroll(event) {    
    if (this.hasScrolledToBottom(event.target)) {
      console.log('Scrolled to bottom');
      this.viewIndex += this.windowSize;      
      this.viewDoctors = this.allDoctors.slice(0,this.viewIndex);      
    }
  }

  private hasScrolledToBottom(target): boolean {    
    return Math.abs(target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop - target.clientHeight) < this.PIXEL_TOLERANCE;
  }

  reset() {
    this.viewDoctors = this.allDoctors.slice(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Find the [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-load-on-scroll-6kzvfo?embed=1&file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const panel = this.selectElem.panel.nativeElement;
panel.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  if (event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight) {
    console.log('scrolled at end');
  }
});
```

by the help of this code you can achieve scroll end event on mat-option elements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).