# angular material mat-select drop-down width

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

The current drop-down box has width greater than the the width of the line: 
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the extra width?
[image]

Here is my current code:

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering placeholder="Choose an option">
      <mat-option [value]="option" *ngFor="let option of my_list">
          {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

my_list:

```
export const my_list: string[] = [ "a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

style.css:

```
.mat-select-panel{
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605953/how-to-use-scroll-event-in-angular-material-mat-select

Comment: Hi RikG93, I don't think two posts are talking about the same thing. Here I want to reduce the width of the scrollable panel. The answer in the link provides a solution to load more when scrolling down in the scrollable panel.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same.

Comment: This is till a bug but here is a work around i found: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14515

Comment: Did you try adding a class to the form container and set its width?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still trying to figure out without making the actual select smaller or wider.

The mat-select-panel uses 100% of the mat-select width plus 32px

```
min-width: calc(100% + 32px)
```

You can override this styling with ng-deep:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this and change width:

```
   <mat-select style="width:10px">
```

Comment: This moves the location of the mat-select-arrow. Is it possible to have the mat-select-arrow at the end and the width of scrollable panel = the width of the underline?

Comment: no this change the width, no the location. You could try min-width: calc(100%- 30px) where 30px is an example

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> .mat-select-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]){
>       min-width: calc(100% + 0px) !important; }

Answer (score 2):

set width at mat-form-field tag level. 
 try this,

```
<mat-form-field style="width:50px">
```

Answer (score 0):

\add class to mat-form-field tag

\and write style to that class

```css
.input-container {
  width: 100%;
  \\  enter code here
}
```