# How to reset BehaviorSuject values for msInfiniteScroll?

Tags: angular, rxjs, infinite-scroll

I copied Haidar's example  here ([how to use scroll event in angular material mat select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605953/how-to-use-scroll-event-in-angular-material-mat-select/54781184#54781184)), to make an infinite scroll for an application. I works as expected, infinite scroll calls getNextBatch() function to obtain the next values. But, I need to reset this values when an user clicks a button, or another event.

I'm using angular 6, this is my code:

This is my html:

```
<mat-select msInfiniteScroll (infiniteScroll)="getNextBatch()" placeholder="Select..." [complete]="offset === array.length"
      (selectionChange)="setValues($event.value)">
      <mat-option [value]="-1"> None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options$ | async" [value]="option.ID">
          {{option.ID}}
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

My js file is:

```
limit = 10;
offset = 0;
options = new BehaviorSubject<VListaDocAttachEntity[]>([]);
options$: Observable<VListaDocAttachEntity[]>;
constructor(){
this.options$ = this.options.asObservable().pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    return [...acc, ...curr];
  }, [])
);
}
getNextBatch(noAdvance?: string) {
var result = [];
if (!noAdvance) {//this is the original behavior
  result = this.docNums.slice(this.offset, this.offset + this.limit);
  this.offset += this.limit;
} else { // this is the optional behavior
  var cnt: number = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.docNums.length; i++) {
    this.documento.forEach(element => {
     if(this.docNums[i].Doc == element.DocNum){
        cnt++
      }
    });
    if (cnt == 0) {
      result.push(this.docNums[i]);
    }else{
      cnt =0;
    }
  }
}

this.options.next(result);//this appends to the list more elements
}
```

When I use the optional behavior, I create a new list from the original list, removing elements that I already selected, and want to replace in my mat-select the previous values, with the new filtered ones.

But the only method is next()  and that appends more elements. So what I want is to reset those values, and append the new list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appends more elements is not `next` but the `scan` operator. One possible solution is to remove the `scan` and do the appending inside `getNextBatch` by accessing the `BehaviourSubject`'s `value` property, like this:

```
limit = 10;
offset = 0;
options = new BehaviorSubject<VListaDocAttachEntity[]>([]);
options$: Observable<VListaDocAttachEntity[]>;
constructor(){
// CHANGED
this.options$ = this.options.asObservable();
}
getNextBatch(noAdvance?: string) {
var result = [];
if (!noAdvance) {//this is the original behavior
  // CHANGED
  result = [...this.options.value, ...this.docNums.slice(this.offset, this.offset + this.limit)];
  this.offset += this.limit;
} else { // this is the optional behavior
  var cnt: number = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.docNums.length; i++) {
    this.documento.forEach(element => {
     if(this.docNums[i].Doc == element.DocNum){
        cnt++
      }
    });
    if (cnt == 0) {
      result.push(this.docNums[i]);
    }else{
      cnt =0;
    }
  }
}

this.options.next(result);
}
```