# detect the end of a webpage with javascript in webview

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I'm using th following code to detect the end of a page is reached with javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if (((document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight)) {
        alert("Bottom of page");
    }
};
```

It works in chrome for desktop but not in the android webview

Comment: Tried these suggestions?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: Yes, the ones with no jQuery (I'm not using it) didn't work