# I want to show a button when android webview reach bottom

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have added a webview inside a dialog. I want to enable the dialog positive button when the user has scrolled the webview to the bottom, so that I can assume that the user has read the user agreement.

Comment: show ur xml flie

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it via Javascript. In the webpage, add the JS code to detect if the user has scrolled to the bottom like this (credits to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom) )

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        Android.onUserScrolledToBottom()
    }
});
```

Then in your Android app, create a Javascript Interface class

```
class MyJavascriptInterface {
    TermsAndCondActivity termsAndCondActivity;

    MyJavascriptInterface(TermsAndCondActivity termsAndCondActivity) {
        this.termsAndCondActivity = termsAndCondActivity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onUserScrolledToBottom() {
        termsAndCondActivity.onUserScrolledToBottom();
    }
}
```

Finally in your TermsAndCondActivity, setup the WebView in the onCreate like this

```
myWebView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_web_view);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

And add the following method

```
void onUserScrolledToBottom() {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

As an example I've used an activity since you didn't specify the dialog's code, but you should be able to adapt the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I have achieved this using onScrollChange() method.

```
   webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

                        if(i1>=webView.getContentHeight()){
                            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }else {
                            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```