# How to determine if the scroll bar is at the very bottom in a verticle scroll height

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with some codes in it. What I want is to determine if the user has scrolled to the very bottom of the page, **determine using a scroll bar!!**. And because I want to run a certain Javascript code that will affect the user's current page User Interface, what is needed is to **Determine if the scroll bar is at the bottom**, the position where it is not possible to scroll down but to go back up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: Yes, this seems like a duplicate..