# How to run a function when scrolling to the bottom of the page or div?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, overflow

I would like to know how do I execute a javascript function when reaching the end of the div via the overflow scroll. My case is as follows, I want that when the user sees all the posts arranged in such a div, reaching the end of everything, load more content through ajax, and this is the function that I want to run when scrolling down.

Comment: You could refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom then use append method to load your content

Comment: Ok. thank you. It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which shows an alert box once you scroll to the bottom (and disappears once you scroll back up):

```js
$('.watch-scroll').on('scroll', function(e){
  var t = $(this);
  if(t[0].scrollHeight - t.scrollTop() - t.outerHeight() < 1){
    $('.alert').show();
  }else{
    $('.alert').hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.watch-scroll {
  height: 100px;
  width:500px;
  overflow: auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.placeholder{
  height:300px; 
}
.alert{
  width:300px;
  padding:1em;
  color:white;
  background-color:#ff5c5c;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="watch-scroll">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<div class="alert">You have scrolled to the bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a scroll event like the previous answer will work, but if you want the best performance possible, you should use `IntersectionObserver`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    ... All Visible Content Here ...
    <div class="scroll-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, make the `.scroll-bottom` of non-zero height and at the very bottom, and use Javascript to attach an `IntersectionObserver` on it. Then wait till it intersects with `container` and you'll know it's scrolled into view which means you've scrolled to the bottom.

You can use something similar for page scrolling, but you can simply detect intersection with the `viewport`.

You can read up about `IntersectionObserver` further since it's not entirely trivial to implement.

Of course, if performance is not important, you can just use a scroll listener as suggested by the other answer.