# Mozilla Firefox bug or ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I wrote the code and saw a bug in firefox and little bug in chrome

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Mozila Firefox</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                alert('1');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
CONTENT FOR SCROLL
</body>
</html>
```

When I scroll this page in firefox i getting bug which covers the black transparent background browser.

In chrome just more and more alerts.

**Close your tabs in firefox!**
Live: http://forum.xeksec.com/habr/mozilla_crash_or_wtf/

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I can confirm I reproduce this bug in FF11
Your idea is to know when the scroll reach the end of the document?

Comment: @haltabush, yea, I wanted to know when the scroo reach the end of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723532

Answer (score 1):

Edit : 
The above doesn't always work... In fact, I've checked some solutions around, including here in Stack Overflow. What other usually advice have the same problem (eg [Alert using Jquery when Scroll to end of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799542/alert-using-jquery-when-scroll-to-end-of-page))
I'm using FF11 on Ubuntu.

I think this was a performance issue. If you put your maxScroll in a variable it works (at least for me)
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Mozila Firefox</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var maxScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop()  == maxScroll){
                alert('1');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hem, it worked, it doesn't anymore. We'll find a solution :)