# Making an infinite scroll from hard-coded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I've been attempting to make an infinite (well semi-infinite) scroll that feeds itself from hard-coded divs (because I don't know any back-end languages yet).  My research has turned up a ton of great jQuery for infinite scrolls, but they are all meant to be used with a database, not hard-coded content.

What I'm trying to achieve, ultimately, is an infinite scroll that starts by loading X div into the DOM, and as the user reaches the bottom of the page, loads X more divs, and repeats until no more divs are left to load.

Do any of you know of some good or relevant scripts or any fiddles that may help me?  Part of my issue is that I'm still in that learning curve of JS; I often understand what's going on when I look at a script but I still have a hard time writing my own from scratch.

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where are those hard coded divs? In your HTML, or in the js code? I mean, is the scroller supposed to just toggle their visibility, or actually insert them into the DOM?

Comment: The hard-coded divs are in the HTML.  I'd prefer that the scroller actually inserts them into the DOM so load-time can be optimized if the divs become image-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code here: [Alert using Jquery when Scroll to end of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799542/alert-using-jquery-when-scroll-to-end-of-page#3800470)

Create a new `<div>` element when you reach the bottom of the page

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight)
    {
        $('body').append('<div></div>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML needs to be stored somewhere and if you have enough of it to think about infinite scrolling you probably don’t want to load it all with the initial request, so let’s say each “post” is stored in an individual HTML file on your server: `/posts/1.html`. And you want to append those to a div in your main document: `<div id="posts"></div>`.

You need a method to download a given post and append it to your div:

```
function loadPost (id) {
  $.get('/posts/'+id+'.html').done(function (html) {
    $('#posts').append(html);
  });
}
```

Now you need a way to trigger `loadPost()` when you scroll to the bottom of the page. This example uses [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to call a handler function when the bottom of the div comes into view:

```
var currentPost = 1;

$('#posts').waypoint({
  offset: 'bottom-in-view',
  handler: function () {
    loadPost(currentPost++);
  }
});
```