# Scroll to bottom of page, only if the user already was at the bottom before DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to learn how to use `window.scrollTo`.

Here's is the desired behavior:

1. Determine if the user is scrolled to the bottom of the page, or no scroll bar is visible
2. Then I want to grow a DIV, this is working
3. If #1 was true, use `window.scrollTo` to scroll to the bottom of the page after the DIV has grown which changed the window height.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Working from Han's idea, we can detect whether the window is scrolled to the bottom like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var shouldScroll = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height();
    $('<div>added content</div>').appendTo('body');
    if(shouldScroll) {
      $(window).scrollTop(document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
});
```

Updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKovacs/nQntc/1/

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to check whether you're at the bottom of the page or not. Using Gaby's answer to [Determining when scrolled to bottom of a page with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript) I get:

```
function scrollbarAtBottom() {
    var totalHeight, currentScroll, visibleHeight;

    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    else
        currentScroll = document.body.scrollTop;

    totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    visibleHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (totalHeight <= currentScroll + visibleHeight)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Next, you can manipulate the DOM and scroll to the bottom if the value returned by `scrollbarAtBottom` was `true`:

```
var atBottom = scrollbarAtBottom();

/* do some stuff */

if (atBottom)
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    else
        document.body.scrollTop = document.body.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).scrollTop(document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/nQntc/

Comment: This doesn't check if the user was at the bottom of the page *before* the DOM was altered.

Comment: I thought it was only #3 that he needed help with.