# How to check if scrollbar is at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you check if the scroll bar is positioned at the bottom? Using JQuery or JavaScript

Comment: yeah but its not working

Comment: the horizontal scroll bar or the verticle one?

Comment: @redoc01 then post your code so we can correct it

Comment: @redoc01 Have a look at my revised answer. I also provided a jsfiddle for a demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining when scrolled to bottom of a page with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working well for my chat window. It also detects if the content isn't long enough to be scrolled.

```
function atBottom(ele) {
    var sh = ele.scrollHeight;
    var st = ele.scrollTop;
    var ht = ele.offsetHeight;
    if (ht == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return st == sh - ht;
}
```

Update: Someone suggested this edit for a cleaner version of the same code. I like my more verbose version as an answer, but its a good idea to have both available.

```
function atBottom(el) {
    let sh = el.scrollHeight,
        st = el.scrollTop,
        ht = el.offsetHeight;
    return ht == 0 || st == sh - ht; 
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You find the height of the scrolling container, then compare that to the scroll position. If they are the same, then you have reached the bottom.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 500px">
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('div').scroll(function()
   {
      var div = $(this);
      if (div.height() == div.scrollTop() + 1) //scrollTop is 0 based
      {
          alert('Reached the bottom!");
      }
   });
});
```

Edit: a little testing in a js fiddle and I realized the previous version is incorrect.
You can use a DOM property to find out how much scrolling there is a perform a little math with the height of the element like so

```
      var div = $(this);
      if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height())
      {
          alert('Reached the bottom!');
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aet2x/1/

Comment: [scrollHeight was not introduced in IE until version 8, though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @DavidHedlund If he is looking for a IE 6 and 7 compatible approach then this won't work, you are correct. He hasn't given any details about browser support requirements.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - however, if I compare it to div.innerHeight instead, it works. I'm assuming margin/padding is playing into this somehow? I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').scroll(function(){
    //scrollTop refers to the top of the scroll position, which will be scrollHeight - offsetHeight
    if(this.scrollTop == (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight)) {
      console.log("Top of the bottom reached!");
    }
  });
});
```

Taken from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-check-div-scrolled/).

Comment: Taken from here. helped me , as i was expecting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element `scrollTop` is equal to the element `innerHeight`.

```
if($('div').scrollTop() == $('div').innerHeight()){
    //Reached the bottom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without any additional library:

```
const elem = document.querySelector(".container");
Math.abs(elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight - elem.scrollTop) <= 1;
```

> `scrollTop` is a non-rounded number, while `scrollHeight` and
> `clientHeight` are rounded — so the only way to determine if the
> scroll area is scrolled to the bottom is by seeing if the scroll
> amount is close enough to some threshold (in this example, that should
> be 1).

Reference: [Scroll height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)