# how to check if the scrollbar has reached at the end of div?

Tags: javascript

```
function yHandler () {

    var show = document.getElementById('show');
    var contentHeight = show.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = show.pageYOffset;
    var y = yOffset + show.innerHeight;

    if(y >= contentHeight) {
        alert("ok")
        }
    }
    show.onscroll  = yHandler;
```

how to check if the scrollbar has reached the end of div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480466/how-to-check-if-scrollbar-is-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some code for you to work on:

```
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

scroll.onscroll = function(){
    var total = scroll.scrollTop + scroll.clientHeight;

    if(total == content.clientHeight)
        alert('Reached bottom!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EY6qP/

Answer (score 1):

Thor's method works perfectly well (+1), but you could also rely on `scrollHeight`.

```
(function(scroll){
  scroll.onscroll = function(){
    if (scroll.scrollTop + scroll.clientHeight == scroll.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('hither!');
    }
  }
})(document.getElementById('scroll'));
```

Comment: Yea, this looks like a more elegant solution, for sure :) Mine was just a quick proof-of-concept, those tend to be ugly ;)

Comment: @rexhin Cheers, should be fixed now.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen -- Cheers, but nothing ugly in using an extra wrapping element though, have done so myself a number of times :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollHeight`, `scrollTop` and `clientHeight` attributes to detect the scroll bar reached bottom end or not.

```
function handleScroll() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div-id");
    if(Math.abs(Math.round(div.scrollHeight - div.scrollTop) - div.clientHeight) > 3) {
        console.log("Scroll bar reached bottom end");   
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```