# Unable to detect if scrolled to the bottom of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code(only works in chrome),
all browsers can detect scroll event: `$(".container").on('scroll', function() {`

But not if its scrolled to the bottom of div(I need help to change this line of code)

```
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
```

full script:

```
$(".container").on('scroll', function() {
   if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
      alert('ok');
   }  

})
```

Tried: 
1)

```
var elem = $(this);
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight())
```

2)

```
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].clientHeight) {
```

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/a/19005567/1565424 will help you!

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828275/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-check-if-a-div-is-scrolled-all-the-way-to-the-bottom

Comment: @ManojShevate, thanks referring to the link, i changed $(this)[0].scrollHeight to $(this)[0].clientHeight...it works now

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the div on scroll and then use

```
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
```

It works for me.

```
$(function($)
  {
    $('.container').bind('scroll', function()
                              {
                                if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                                {
                                  alert('end reached');
                                }
                              })
  }
);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/w7X9N/2266/)**

Answer (score 0):

If your div has some padding or margin, you can use outerHeight() instead of innerHeight(), this worked for me:

```
if((element.scrollTop() + element.outerHeight()) >= element[0].scrollHeight)
```