# Jquery Mobile lazy load with listview filter from SQLite

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to get lazy loading to work with my JQuery Mobile-Cordova app, the idea is a list of 100+ items to be loaded from the SQLite DB stored on the phone with lazy loading but still enabling to search the items using the *data-filter="true"* attribute.

I use the following code to load the items (from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robincharummoottil/YdEDx/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var eventsElement = $('#resultListView');
    $(window).bind('scrollstop', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#page1').height() - 500) {
            eventsElement.append('<li><a href="">Stop</a></li>');
            eventsElement.listview('refresh');
        }
    });

});
```

It works fine, I load the database according to what I need (LIMIT, OFFSET), now the problem is that the *data-filter="true"* attribute only filters the items loaded on the list, thus leaving my "unloaded" items out of the search.

What would be the appropriate approach for dealing with such data? I looked into [here](http://dcarrith.github.com/jquery.mobile.lazyloader/) but it needs to pull the data from a server side, which in this case is not what I have/need. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786876/jquery-mobile-lazy-load-list-items

Comment: @Mayu Mayooresan it is not. I need to be able to use the filter from JQuery Mobile eventhough not all items are loaded from the DB, which in that case is not happening...