# How to know when element has been scrolled to the bottom

Tags: javascript, uiscrollview, scrolltop

According to the first answer to the question at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript), it can be known when `element.innerHeight` + `element.scrollTop` is greater than or equal to `element.offsetHeight`. Shouldn't it be **`element.innerHeight` + `element.scrollTop` is greater than or equal to `element.scrollHeight`**? `offsetHeight` just includes the padding while calculating the visible height, what we want here is to find whether the scrolled height plus the visible height equals the total height, isn't the total height given by `scrollHeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes. However, that question is about the page specifically, and the `<body>` element doesn't actually scroll; the viewport does.

Try it out: make sure this page scrolls, then open a console:

```
> document.body.offsetHeight === document.body.scrollHeight
true
```

Comment: Oh, ok. So surely that code won't work for normal page elements?

Comment: Any idea about the browser support of `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` properties? Do they work in IE 5+? I have Googled extensively, couldn't find convenient answers!

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Nope, I can't find any information either, and I don't have IE6 or lower to test with. But it works on any reasonably modern browser.

Comment: Yeah I know that would work with Javascript, wanted to know how to make it work without. Surely there has to be a solution (it's a pretty big bug, you can't design fixed-height elements without Javascript!), somehow it is eluding Google!

Comment: @Cupidvogel: What do you mean by fixed-height elements? I thought this question was about detecting when the user scrolls an element to the bottom...

Comment: Oh sorry, I was simultaneously answering two questions, posted the right comment in the wrong place! :(