# Make fixed div stop at footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

i know there are other solutions to this problem, but i simply cant get them to work

i have a fixed div that sticks to the bottom. i would like i to stop when it hits the #footer

[the site](http://spotonmarketing.dk.linux11.curanetserver.dk/om-os/)

is have is css so basically i need a script that changes the class from .widget.widget_nav_menu to .widget.widget_nav_menu.fixed_button when is hits the border of the footer

is that possible?

```
.widget.widget_nav_menu{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E3337;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2%;
  color: #707480;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.widget.widget_nav_menu.fixed_button {
  margin-right: -210px;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -180px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E3337;
  padding: 25px;
  right: 2%;
}
```

Comment: are you want to hide in bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of answers floating around on StackOverflow that answer your question if JavaScript can dectect if the page has hit the bottom or not:

- [Determining when JavaScript scrolled bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript)
- [How to Detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

With the help of the above, you change simply change the Class once it has:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){

       //Cache the Footer Widget
       var $footerMenu = $('.widget.widget_nav_menu');

       //Check if it hits the bottom, toggle Relevant Class.
       if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)
          $footerMenu.addClass('fixed_button');
       else
          $footerMenu.removeClass('fixed_button');

    });
});
</script>
```

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/fVKZe/1/

To include this into a WordPress setup, you'll need to add a custom `.js` file and queue it until jQuery has loaded in WordPress as a dependency.

**stickymenu.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        //The Above Footer Widget Code
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
function stickyfooter_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'stickymenu',
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/stickymenu.js',
         array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stickyfooter_method' );
```

Comment: i should put this script in my header?

Comment: Your site is a WordPress site (I think), thus you'll need to include your JavaScript after jQuery is loaded (Currently it's loading before jQuery is loaded in the footer). You should include it in a .js file, then queue it in functions.php.

Comment: @user2979600 Updated my answer to include Wordpress custom JavaScript

Comment: I addet the script to my header.php.
created a stickymenu.js to my /js/ folder.
add the code to my functions.php..

still not working.. im not good at this JS thing so a really can't help my self.. :)..

Comment: You where a bit fast with your answer :)... 

I addet the script to my header.php. created a stickymenu.js to my /js/ folder. add the code to my functions.php.. still not working.. im not good at this JS thing so a really can't help my self.. :)..

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake on the functions.php, please change `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stickyfooter' );` to `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stickyfooter_method' );` and change `/js/stickyfooter.js` to `/js/stickymenu.js/` so sorry!

Comment: Finally, you can just copy-paste this JavaScript on this link into `stickymenu.js` http://jsfiddle.net/a95N2/ :)! (The jQuery(document)..) part, and not to worry!

Comment: so where do i put the script?

Comment: @user2979600 Sorry for the two mistakes I made, if you correct them and place the linked JavaScript into `stickymenu.js`, it should work!

Comment: Well the page doesn't have `.widget_nav_menu` anymore so it won't change anything, it's now `#menu_bottom` right? `$('.widget.widget_nav_menu');` to `$('#menu_bottom')`

Comment: I think your `functions.php` still references my previous mistake, sorry! `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/stickyfooter.js'`, to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/stickymenu.js'`,

Comment: Nice one! :D Now it can find your stickymenu.js script, last thing to do is change it go `#menu_bottom` ;)

Comment: That would of been much faster if I didn't make the couple of mistakes in my answer, Sorry! Glad it works :)!! @user2979600

Comment: one more question, if you got more time to help me. What if i wanted the menu to stop 168px above the bottom :)

Comment: You'd change the `if` statement to subtract the `<footer>` height, adjust: `if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)` into: `if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight - document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight )`

Comment: Anytime =)! Glad to help!