# Check if the scroll is currently at the bottom - no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

What is the easiest way to check if the window scroll is at the bottom—without using `jQuery`?

I've come across some methods, but most of them don't work cross browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining when scrolled to bottom of a page with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817042/determining-when-scrolled-to-bottom-of-a-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one technique that works across a handful of browsers I tested

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var totalHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrollTop = (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)
    ? document.body.scrollTop : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (totalHeight == scrollTop + clientHeight)
        console.log('Bottom');
}
```